# Can you combine radio button choices from multiple forms in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, multiple-forms

I'm teaching myself VB and on one of the Programming Challenges says, "Create an application with 2 forms. The startup form holds the names of the dormitories and the other holds the meal plans. When the user selects the dormitory and meal plan, the application should show the total charges for the semester on the start up form."

What I did was add radio buttons on the first form so the user can select the dorm they want. I added a button which then displays the second form where I also added radio buttons. There they can choose what meal plan they want. Is there a way I can import what the user picked in the first form so I can add it to the choices made on the second form?  Thanks in advance!

Form 2:

```
Public Class MealForm

Private Sub btnMealClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMealClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    Dim txtFirstChoice As Integer
    Dim frmMain As New MainForm

    If rad7Meals.Checked = True Then
        txtFirstChoice = 560
    ElseIf rad14Meals.Checked = True Then
        txtFirstChoice = 1095
    ElseIf radUnlimitedMeals.Checked = True Then
        txtFirstChoice = 1500

        End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Form 1:

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub btnAddMeal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddMeal.Click
        Dim frmMeal As New MealForm

        frmMeal.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Could you include the code you have so far?

Comment: I added some of the code that I currently have. It's my first time using multiple forms this is all I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it would be to place a property on frmMeal like so:

```
Public Class MealForm

    Public Property DormCost as Integer

    Private Sub btnMealClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMealClose.Click
      Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
      Dim totalCost as Integer
      Dim mealCost as Interger 
      mealCost = cost based on radio button choice for meals        
      totalCost = mealCost + Me.DormCost
    End Sub
End Class
```

Set the PlanCost variable after declaration and before the show:

```
Public Class MainForm
     Private Sub btnAddMeal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddMeal.Click
         Dim frmMeal As New MealForm
         frmMeal.DormCost = pass cost based on radio button choice to meal form here    
         frmMeal.ShowDialog()
     End Sub    
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial will put you on the right track http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/332553-passing-data-between-forms/